# How safe it is to pass a model-object ID as a parameter in a request?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, web-development-server

I'm new to web development, so here's the situation: I have a model named **Qualifier**, that has a name and several other fields. It has a reference to 1 and only 1 User, but doesn't have any other unique fields. e.g.:

```
class Qualifier(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    other_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I also have a view that loads, in a list, all Qualifier objects that belong to the accessing User: they are fetched by the fields *user* since there's no other "unique field" to distinguish.

```
def qualifiers_view(request):
    # Access Restriction
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("accounts:login")

    # Fetch company users
    qualifiers = Qualifier.objects.filter(
        user=request.user
    )

    return render(request, 'qualifiers.html', {'qualifiers': qualifiers})
```

But here's a problem: In the view template, within each row of this list, beside each Qualifier, there's a **DELETE** button (a "POST" form) intended to call a *view* that deletes that same Qualifier,  based on the parameter(s) passed... but it seems inefficient to me to pass *user* and *name* as the parameters, because it would result in another search through the database to find it.

I thought: An other option would be to get the Qualifier object's ID's in the DB upon the first search (when the list loads), associate each one with its own delete button, and let it be the parameter for that delete view, resulting in an instant deletion.

```
  {% for q in qualifiers %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{q.name}}</td>
    <td>
      <form action="{%url 'delete_qualifier' id %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="Delete qualifier" class='btn btn-primary'>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

But how recommended is it? Even considering that I can deny non-authorized users inside the view trying to throw delete requests with random ID's maliciously.. would it be safe to EVEN put an database ID in the frontend? Should I stick with the original way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought: An other option would be to get the Qualifier object's ID's in the DB upon the first search (when the list loads), associate each one with its own delete button, and let it be the parameter for that delete view, resulting in an instant deletion.

Searching by a column for which there is an index will boost efficiency significantly. Verifying that this item belongs to the user will take not much extra time, and is a good idea from security point-of-view.

You should however validate that the user is allowed to delete that object, since otherwise everyone can delete some else's `Qualifier` objects.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

@login_required
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def delete_quantifier(request, pk):
    qualifiers = Qualifier.objects.filter(
        pk=pk,
        user_id=request.user.pk
    ).delete()
    return redirect('accounts:login')
```

In the url, you can thus specify a `pk` parameter:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # …,
    path('delete/<int:pk>/', views.delete_quantifier, name='delete_quantifier'),
]
```

and in the template, you can resolve the url with:

```
<form action="{%url 'delete_quantifier' pk=q.pk %}" method="POST">
```

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
>   [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Comment: Thanks, your answer really clarified a lot. About the decorators, I thought they were only for class based views. Since that's not the case, I'll start using them.